# What order should I approach advanced algebraic geometry in?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

[My mathematical background: uneven, but very strong in type theory and proof theory, theory of formal
languages and abstract rewriting, logic, and intermediate real analysis; advanced knowledge of category theory, intermediate algebraic geometry and homotopy theory, some basic exposure to things like CW complexes, simplical complexes]

With each mathematical structure I comprehend well I associate a graph of “conceptual dependencies” to it; sadly this graph often has cycles and it can make it hard to know where to start when explaining a new topic. For example, mastering basic category theory is aided by a decent understanding of set theory (difficult to understand representable functors and thus presheaves and the Yoneda lemma without them) … understanding general notions of equivalence and isomorphism helps. As does a decent understanding of foundational concerns, Grothendieck universes, linear algebra, topology. group theory, etc. a lot of machinery.

Anyway, I want to get more into algebraic geometry and I’d like to understand the work that has been done in the theory of motives. What order should I approach this? Varieties first? Cohomology theories? Grothendieck’s standard conjectures? Kato-Bloch conjecture? Voevodsky’s work?

I’d appreciate any advice.

Comment: I do endorse your perception that mathematics is not "logically ordered", despite some popular claims, although, of course, we can pretend to do so (artificially). No more logically ordered than "real life" (if we imagine that mathematics is a part of real life...). So, yes, as you anticipate, things are a bit messy... inescapably. My point would be that it is highly artificial to think in terms of fake logical ordering, and does not aid understanding... contrary, perhaps, to formalists' claims that logical ordering (artificial or not) is the key to understanding, etc. Tastes vary, of course.

Comment: Well there are many ways to define some concepts which might be more appropriate depending on how much you know and how articulate or a conceptual apparatus you are using. For example, in univalvent foundations a set is the type { A : Type | forall a, b : A, p : a = b, q : a = b => p = q } { a set is a type where where all proofs that two elements of a and b are equal are themselves equal (contractible) } — here we have an example of homotopic notions engulfing the set theoretic foundation they were once purported to depend on.

Comment: Questions like this tend to get closed on this site. You can try to improve it, by saying what your background is. The answer to your first question very much depends on it. My own advice is that if you don't already know what a variety is, then learn that first.

Comment: Thanks. I added some background. It’s difficult to describe as I am self-taught in mathematics. Originally I learned set theory as a young kid and first order logic. Went on to learn a lot about topology. Very meticulously surveyed a lot of areas in depth with focus on developing mathematical taste and intuition. ... main difficulty is my unorthodox background and the feeling that I am lacking some of the tacit folklore that motivates some of the higher AG stuff; Grothendieck’s supposed quest to find *the* cohomology theory makes sense to me but how this interacts with the rest not sure

Comment: OK, I see. It's  long road to motives. But  probably you can start with  a book on algebraic geometry like Hartshorne's, with a book on commutative algebra on the side.  If you know topology, including manifolds, that helps a lot with the intuition.

Comment: Thank you. That’s very helpful.